# How to interpret CBOW word embeddings?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

In context of word2vec, it is said that "words occurring in similar contexts have similar word embeddings"; for example, "love" and "hate" may have similar embeddings because they appear in contextual words such as "I" and "movie", just for an example.

I get the intuition with skip-gram: both embeddings of "love" and "hate" should predict the context words "I" and "movie", thus the embeddings should be similar. However, I can't get it with CBOW: it says that the average embeddings of "I" and "movie" should predict "love" and "hate"; does that necessarily lead to that the embeddings of "love" and "hate" should be similar? Or do we interpret word embeddings of SG and CBOW in different ways?

Answer (score 0):

In practice it's all smoothed out by the diversity of contexts in CBOW – so the same intuition that works for skip-gram should also apply to CBOW.

Even if 'movie' is only 1/Nth of an influence on the average vector of all context words, when that average vector gets backpropagation-corrected to slightly more predictive of 'love' (for a single training-example), each word contributing to it is also backpropagation-corrected.

Over all examples, and all passes, corrections that pull in random directions tend to cancel each other out, but any consistent tendencies – like two words often co-occurring – tend to reinforce similar correction-nudges on their word-vectors, moving them near each other. (Or, other words that are like a word in other aspects.)

Skip-gram is the stark, simple version: force word X to be more predictive of word Y – but expect that lots of other 1:1 corrections will all balance out. CBOW does things in batches: force words X^1, X^2, ... X^n to all be more predictive of word Y - but expect that lots of other somewhat-overlapping batches will pull distinct words together/apart as needed.